# SQLite 3 Query: Finding People with maximum values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working with SQLite3 and I have 4 tables:

```
FROM classmate s, tookclass t, class c, classsection sec
WHERE s.sid = t.sid AND sec.secid = t.secid AND c.dept = 'CompSci';
```

My code here will output ALL student ids that have taken a class in the department of 'CompSci'.

I am very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from Classmate s       
where Exists (Select * From Class c
                 join ClassSection cs on cs.crsid = c.crsid
                 join tookClass tc on tc.secid = cs.secid
              where tc.sid = s.sid
                  and c.dept = 'CompSci'
              group by tc.sid
              having count(*) = 1)
```

or

```
Select * from Classmate s       
where Exists (Select * From Class c
                 join ClassSection cs on cs.crsid = c.crsid
                 join tookClass tc on tc.secid = cs.secid
              where tc.sid = s.sid
                  and c.dept = 'CompSci')  -- there is one, ....
     and Not exists 
             (select * from Class c1
                 join ClassSection cs1 on cs1.crsid = c1.crsid
                 join tookClass tc1 on tc1.secid = cs1.secid
              where tc.sid = s.sid
                  and c1.dept = 'CompSci'
                  and c1.crsid <> c.crsid)  -- but there is NOT another
```

Comment: This was very, very helpful. I think I tried the code before you were finished typing. Thanks again.